# asp.net create user control & SQL server storage

Tags: asp.net, sql, login-control, createuserwizard

I am creating a site and adding some users with the create user wizzard, however hosting the site on ASPSpider (free hosting) requires me to attach the database to their server and this process means the database used will not be in the App_Data folder.

I have tried to configure the SQL provider to use the connection string ascociated with the DB

```
    <membership>
  <providers>
    <add name="createUserSqlMembershipProvider"
    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionString"
    enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
    enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
    applicationName="/"
    requiresUniqueEmail="false"
    passwordFormat="Hashed"
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
    minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
    minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
    passwordAttemptWindow="10"
    passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

However when I then create a user from the site this doesn't use the database I have set up, it creates its own one within the App_Data folder. Any ideas, or if you need more info just let me know?

Another problem is that my login control also needs to use this db but doesn't seem to want to. I know the db is in use because one of the other pages uses it in a page load event to retrieve posts made by users, so the connection string is correct.

Thanks,

Si

Comment: I have now configured the site using the ASP.net configuration utility and on the providers had to select for seperate ones, this seems to work. However now I have another problem, each time I fire up the site if I create a user it (the site) creates an App_Data folder and puts in it a database (with the same schema as the one I already have the connection string pointing to) but I don't need it to create this new db, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<clear />` right after your `<providers>` tag, this will remove the default providers and add only your provider.